# Fundamental solution Laplace-Poisson equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the fundamental solution of the Laplace equation (see e.g. in the book of Evans). For a function $f\in\mathcal{C}_c^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we define the function 
$$u(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(y)f(x-y)dy$$
(which finally should turn out to be a solution of the Poisson equation, but I'm not interested in this fact here). What I want to prove now is that this function $u$ is continuous. Does somebody know how to do this?
I attempted to use that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is unfortunately not the case for $\Phi$. Hence when I let a sequence $x_n$ of vectors approach some $x$, I do not know why it is possible to interchange limit and integration. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Try $\frac{u(x+he_i)-u(x)}{h}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(y)\{\frac{f(x+he_i-y)-f(x-y)}{h}\}dy$. Then  $\frac{f(x+he_i-y)-f(x-y)}{h}\rightarrow\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x-y)$ uniformly(!) in $h$ and of course $u\in C^1$ implies $u\in C^0$. Similarly You can show $u\in C^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think to follow your suggestion poses the same problem: Why does the uniform convergence of $\frac{f(x-y+he_i)-f(x-y)}{h}$ imply the convergence of the desired integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(y)\frac{f(x-y+he_i)-f(x-y)}{h}dy$? Is there a way to prove uniform convergence of its integrand?

Comment: OK Clearly $sup_{y\in supp(f)}|\Phi(y)(\frac{f(x-y+he_i)-f(x-y)}{h}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i})|\rightarrow 0,h\rightarrow 0$ and then $|\int_{supp(f)}\Phi(y)(\frac{f(x-y+he_i)-f(x-y)}{h}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i})|\rightarrow 0,h\rightarrow 0$ if $f$ has a support of finite measure, Ithink You need this assumption.

Comment: Ok, my support is compact whence it has finite measure. But, how do you obtain the uniform convergence of $\Phi(y)\frac{f(x-y+he_i)-f(x-y)}{h}$ as $h\to 0$? This is exactly the doubtful point for me since $\Phi$ has a singularity at $0$.

Comment: You are perfectly right, it´s not clear at all...may bee then $\int_{B_{\epsilon}}|\Phi(y)|dy\leq C\epsilon^2|log \epsilon|$or if $n\geq 3$ even $C\epsilon^2$ might help You?

Comment: Yes, this should help when I split up the integral on $B_\epsilon\cap\mathrm{supp}(f)$ and the rest. Thank you!

Comment: Good point!...not as easy as it seemed to be at a first glance.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is the Dominated Convergence Theorem, in order to pass the limit through the integral sign. Let $F(t)=\int\limits_a^b f(x,t)dx$ where $f$ and $f_t$ are continuous.  Then $$\frac{F(t+h)-F(t)}{h}=\int\limits_a^b\frac{f(x,t+h)-f(x,t)}{h}dx$$ $$=\int\limits_a^bf_t(x,t+\theta h)dx$$ for some $\theta\in(0,1)$ [Mean Value Theorem].

Being continuous on a compact set, $f_t$ is bounded. Let $|f_t(x,t+\theta h)|\leq M$ for all $h$ (perhaps sufficiently small). Also, $f_t(x,t+\theta h)\rightarrow f_t(x,t)$ as $h\rightarrow 0$. So by Dominated Convergence Theorem, $$F'(t)=\int\limits_a^b f_t(x,t)dx$$

In your case you are simply working on each components. So the same argument works.